# How to extract the value of "name" from this puppet metadata.json without jq in shell?

Tags: json, regex, shell, unix, puppet

For some extreme reason, I can't use jq or other cli tool. I need to extract the value of "name" from any json matching this puppet [metadata.json](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_publishing.html#write-a-metadatajson-file). format.

the json might not be properly formatted and indented but will be valid. Meaning, white spaces, and line breaks, carriage backs might be inserted in eligible places.

Note that there could be "name" elements in dependencies array.

So, how to extract the value only using standard unix commands and/or shell script without installing any application like jq or other tools?

Thank you!!

```
{
  "name": "examplecorp-mymodule",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Pat",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "summary": "A module for a thing",
  "source": "https://github.com/examplecorp/examplecorp-mymodule",
  "project_page": "https://forge.puppetlabs.com/examplecorp/mymodule",
  "issues_url": "https://github.com/examplecorp/examplecorp-mymodule/issues",
  "tags": ["things", "stuff"],
  "operatingsystem_support": [
    {
    "operatingsystem":"RedHat",
    "operatingsystemrelease":[ "5.0", "6.0" ]
    },
    {
    "operatingsystem": "Ubuntu",
    "operatingsystemrelease": [ "12.04", "10.04" ]
    }
   ],
  "dependencies": [
    { "name": "puppetlabs/stdlib", "version_requirement": ">=3.2.0 <5.0.0" },
    { "name": "puppetlabs/firewall", "version_requirement": ">= 0.0.4" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "Or other tools"? You don't even have a Python interpreter? (You can parse JSON with one-liners using `python -m json`). To be clear: jq is universally suggested **because the shell can't reliably do this itself**. One can come up with hacks, but they're *hacks* -- meaning not structurally aware, meaning they can't correctly cope with all the possible corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, awful, horrible, not structure-aware and will give you incorrect results if you have extra contents in your input file that look similar to what you're trying to find -- but...

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^- NOT /bin/sh; shell-native regexes are a bash extension

contents=$(<in.json)
if [[ $contents =~ '"name":'[[:space:]]*'"'([^\"]*)'"' ]]; then
  echo "Found name: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

---

Now, let's talk about some of the ways this answer is broken (and using jq would be better):

- **It finds the *first* name, even if it's not one at an outer nesting layer.** That is to say, if `"dependencies": [ { "name": "puppetlabs/stdlib", "version_requirement": ">=3.2.0 <5.0.0" } ]` comes before `"name": "examplecorp-mymodule"`, guess which result is being found? (The easy workarounds to this would involve making assumptions about whitespace/formatting, and are thus not proof against all possible JSON expressions of the same data).
- It won't unescape contents inside your name that require, well, unescaping (think about names containing symbols encoded as `&foo;`).
- It isn't multibyte-character aware, and thus isn't guaranteed to emit output that aligns on codepoint boundaries.
- If you have a name with an escaped `\"` subsequence... well, guess what happens there?

Etc. It's not quite as awful as trying to parse XML with regular expressions (JSON is easier!), but it's still quite a mess.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
jq '.name' metadata.json
```